# Can you use "after" without it being preceeded or followed by any duration?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language, conjunctions

**I just had them doing stretch routines, and after, they got really good at it.**

We usually see **"after"** being preceeded or followed by something. For instance **"2 hours after something".**

This is the first time I see it being used on its own and it seems to have the meaning **"some time later"**.

Is it correct to use **"after"** like this without putting any duration before or after it?

Comment: Use afterwards instead.

Comment: after that OR afterwards

Answer (score 1):

"After" implies a sequence in time, space, or an abstract space such as priority, but not necessarily a particular duration of time.

It can be an adverb, a preposition, or a conjunction, but there is an implied sequence. See the definition, with examples:

[Merriam-Webster *after*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/after)

After all, it has a lot of different uses, but usually the same sense.

Answer (score -4):

"After" can also be used as an adverb not adding a noun after it in a phrase.

For example, "Dan came to work at 10 o'clock. I came one hour after."

or

"He died on June 3rd and was buried the day after."

[https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/after_1#:~:text=After%20is%20used%20in%20the,a%20phone%20call%20from%20Stuart](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/after_1#:%7E:text=After%20is%20used%20in%20the,a%20phone%20call%20from%20Stuart).

Comment: The question is whether we can use "after" without any time/duration next to it, and both your examples include a time/duration.